# Filter data frame rows based on values in vector

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

What is the best way to filter rows from data frame when the values to be deleted are stored in a vector? In my case I have a column with dates and want to remove several dates.

I know how to delete rows corresponding to *one* day, using `!=`, e.g.:

```
m[m$date != "01/31/11", ]
```

To remove several dates, specified in a vector, I tried:

```
m[m$date != c("01/31/11", "01/30/11"), ]
```

However, this generates a warning message:

```
Warning message:
In `!=.default`(m$date, c("01/31/11", "01/30/11")) :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
Calls: [ ... [.data.frame -> Ops.dates -> NextMethod -> Ops.times -> NextMethod
```

What is the correct way to apply a filter based on multiple values?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

nzcoops is spot on with his suggestion. I posed this question in the R Chat a while back and Paul Teetor suggested defining a new function:

```
`%notin%` <- function(x,y) !(x %in% y)
```

Which can then be used as follows:

```
foo <- letters[1:6]

> foo[foo %notin% c("a", "c", "e")]
[1] "b" "d" "f"
```

Needless to say, this little gem is now in my [R profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189759/expert-r-users-whats-in-your-rprofile) and gets used quite often.

Comment: Nice. I always find it breaks my concentration when I have to type something like `!(x %in% y)`... great tip.

Comment: I don't think `dplyr` can handle this, e.g., 
`filter(df, foo %notin% c("a", "c", "e"))`

Comment: It was just a comment! I was trying to use `%noin%` in a `filter` call and it didn't work, non-suprisingly.

Comment: @MattO'Brien, I posted an equivalent using `anti_join` below . . .

Answer (score 14):

I think for that you want:

```
m[!m$date %in% c("01/31/11","01/30/11"),]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when date is in `as.POSIXct` class !

Answer (score 4):

cool way is to use Negate function to create new one:

```
`%ni%` <- Negate(`%in%`)
```

than you can use it to find not intersected elements

Answer (score 2):

In regards to some of the questions above, here is a `tidyverse` compliant solution. I used `anti_join` from `dplyr` to achieve the same effect:

```
library(tidyverse)

numbers <- tibble(numbers = c(1:10))
numbers_to_remove <- tibble(number = c(3, 4, 5))

numbers %>%
  anti_join(numbers_to_remove)
```