# Removing data from a data frame based on another list

Tags: r, dataframe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Standard way to remove multiple elements from a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494848/standard-way-to-remove-multiple-elements-from-a-dataframe)

I have a large data frame that an example from looks like this:

```
[df]
Sample Assay Genotype X
001    001       T    2356
002    001       C    1892
001    004       T    8
002    004       C    11567
1001   004       T    8385
1001   005       A    604
```

In all the data frame has over 330,000 rows of data.

I am trying to remove certain rows from this data frame based using the values for X which is unique for each row. I have the list of values for X that id like to remove as an object in the 'integer' clas. In this example, id like to remove rows that match 'z':

```
z = 1892 8 604
```

This would result in a new data frame for this example:

```
[df]
Sample Assay Genotype X
001    001       T    2356
002    004       C    11567
1001   004       T    8385
```

Im really not sure how to go about this, although im sure its quite basic. In my real data, the list for `z` is quite long, so I cant simply write out allow of the values id like to remove into the code.

I tried `df[df$X !=z, , drop=F]` and this didnt work. Im not sure how to use the removal list on the larger data frame.

Comment: The answer here is probably what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494848/standard-way-to-remove-multiple-elements-from-a-dataframe

Comment: `subset(df,!X %in% c(1892,8,604))`

Comment: Or `df[df$X != z, , drop=F]`, if you prefer your original syntax.     (`df$X != z` will show you why your code didn't do what you wanted).

Comment: should this be closed as a duplicate of the linked question??

Comment: Sure...ill close it. How do I do that?

Comment: 5 people with appropriate levels of access have to vote to close (4 more now).  I think you could **delete** your own question, but closing is probably better.

Comment: Closing is always better as, in the future, people who search for things in the manner that you have described them will be directed to the duplicate. don't delete your question :)