# Match with negation

Tags: r

This is really simple but I can't seem to locate it.  I know R has a negated version of `%in%` that returns "not in."  Obviously I could just use `!(x %in% y)` , but the language includes an already negated construct and I want to use it, goshdarnit.

So what's the function?  Searches as well as `%nin%` and `%notin%` all fail.

Bonus internets to you if you benchmark your answer versus `!(x %in% y)` using the following sample data:

```
x <- sample( sample(letters,5), 10^3, replace=TRUE)
y <- sample( letters, 10^5, replace=TRUE)
```

Comment: I don't think it does. I just make my own using `Negate`.

Comment: Which begs the question: Is `Negate` any faster/slower than `!`? But seriously, I coulda sworn I've seen it before.

Comment: I think an add on package has what you're after but it's not too rough on the index finger to type `!`.  Especially since your parenthesis are unnecessary. `!x %in% y` works just fine.  I'm guessing that Negate will be slower as often higher order functions are.

Comment: Oh, those pesky packages.  And you're right...I've included the parens for (to me, at least) clarity for so long I forgot that order of operations makes them redundant.  Please Excuse My Darned Annoying Slipup.

Comment: @ttmaccer Yeah, and that's why I like my version: `'%ni%' <- Negate('%in%')`. Soooooo simple.

Comment: I've answered this before, in atleast two locations, here's [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494848/standard-way-to-remove-multiple-elements-from-a-dataframe/7498829#7498829). This is one area where the SO search seems to fail though. I wish we could put all the right search terms in one spot so this could be more easily found.

Comment: @Chase There it is.  Voting to close.  I agree about the search terms.  I tried....

Comment: Would `setdiff` suffice, if `x[!x %in% y]` is the outcome you want.

Comment: ...with the difference that `setdiff` throws away duplicates, so it is more like `unique(x[!x %in% y])`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just out of interest. Defining

```
"%w/o%" <- function(x, y) x[!x %in% y] 
'%ni%' <- Negate('%in%')

> benchmark(y[y%ni%x], y%w/o%x,replications=1000)
         test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child
2   y %w/o% x         1000    5.32 1.000000      4.60     0.70         NA
1 y[y %ni% x]         1000    5.34 1.003759      4.68     0.65         NA
  sys.child
2        NA
1        NA
```

Do i get a cookie?

Comment: You get a cookie for `benchmark(y[y%ni%x], y%w/o%x)`. Can you edit?

Comment: So that is basically a wash -- 0.3% difference is measurement error.  But nice work.

Comment: But maybe lose a cookie for having a `/` in a function name? :-)