# generating a vector of difference between two vectors

Tags: r

I have two csv files, and each of which consists of one column of data

For instance, vecA.csv is like

```
id
1
2
```

vecB.csv is like

```
id
3
2
```

I read the data set as follows:

```
vectorA<-read.table("vecA.csv",sep=",",header=T)
vectorB<-read.table("vecB.csv",sep=",",header=T)
```

I want to generate a vector consisting of elements belonging to B only.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You are looking for the function `setdiff`

```
setdiff(vectorB$id, vectorA$id)
```

If you did not want this reduced to unique values, you could create a `not in` function

(kudos to @joran here [Match with negation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302985/match-with-negation))

```
'%nin%' <- Negate('%in%')

vectorB$id[vectorB$id %nin% vectorA$id]
```

Comment: +111 for `%nin%` !! I think I already have some uses for that one.

Comment: In Frank Harrell's Hmisc package, there's %nin%.

Comment: if a and b are vectors, a[!a %in% b]

Answer (score 13):

If your vector's are instead `data.table`s, then all you need are five characters:

```
B[!A]
```

---

```
library(data.table)

# read in your data, wrap in data.table(..., key="id") 
A <- data.table(read.table("vecA.csv",sep=",",header=T), key="id")
B <- data.table(read.table("vecB.csv",sep=",",header=T), key="id")

# Then this is all you need
B[!A]
```

---

[Matthew] And in v1.8.7 it's simpler and faster to read the file as well :

```
A <- setkey(fread("vecA.csv"), id)
B <- setkey(fread("vecB.csv"), id)
B[!A]
```

Comment: Very slick.  data.table rocks! And it's blazing fast.