# How to subtract two vectors' elements one by one?

Tags: r, vector

I have these two vectors:

```
first<-c(1,2,2,2,3,3,4)
second<-c(1,2)
```

now I want `first` without `second` elements to get result like this:`(2,2,3,3,4)`; indeed,
I don't want all `2`s removed and only want one by one subtracting.

I have tried this (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14949738/generating-a-vector-of-difference-between-two-vectors)):

```
'%nin%' <- Negate('%in%')
first<-first[first %nin% second]
```

but it removes all `2`s from `first` and gives this result: `(3,3,4)`

How can I do that?

Comment: @rawr just the first one! as I said, one by one; does `first[-second]` do one by one?

Comment: I'm confused if `second` should be indices of `first` that you want to remove or a specific pattern of elements from `first` that should be removed.

Comment: @rawr more generic example: let `first` be `(1,2,4,2,3,1,2,3)` and `second` be `(9,2,2,1)`. in this case, intersections are `(2,2,3)`. so two 2 and one 3 should be removed from `first`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
first[-sapply(second, function(x) head(which(is.element(el=first, x)), 1))]
## [1] 2 2 3 3 4
```

This won't work if you have duplicate elements in `second`. In that case, I think you'll need a loop:

```
first2 <- first
for(i in seq_along(second)) {
    first2 <- first2[-head(which(is.element(el=first2, second[i])), 1)]
}
first2
# [1] 2 2 3 3 4

first2 <- first
second <- c(1,2,2)
for(i in seq_along(second)) {
    first2 <- first2[-head(which(is.element(el=first2, second[i])), 1)]
}
first2
## [1] 2 3 3 4
```

Comment: thanks, I'll try it; but is `first[-second]` safe to use for one by one subtracting?

Comment: @majidgeek Try `rev(first)[-second]` and you will see that it is not.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
second<-c(1, 2)
first[-match(second, first)]
## [1] 2 2 3 3 4
```

For a more complected cases, here's an option using `<<-`

```
second <- c(1, 2, 2)
invisible(lapply(second, function(x) first <<- first[-match(x, first)]))
first
## [1] 2 3 3 4
```

Comment: This has the same limitation as my first solution.

Comment: @Thomas, I see. It's still doesn't use `sapply` loops and some other unecessary functions :) I'll work on improvement

Comment: Yes, it's much better than my first solution.