# Why does dplyr's filter drop NA values from a factor variable?

Tags: r, dplyr, subset, na

When I use `filter` from the `dplyr` package to drop a level of a factor variable, `filter` also drops the `NA` values.  Here's an example:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(919)
(dat <- data.frame(var1 = factor(sample(c(1:3, NA), size = 10, replace = T))))
#    var1
# 1  <NA>
# 2     3
# 3     3
# 4     1
# 5     1
# 6  <NA>
# 7     2
# 8     2
# 9  <NA>
# 10    1

filter(dat, var1 != 1)
#   var1
# 1    3
# 2    3
# 3    2
# 4    2
```

This does not seem ideal -- I only wanted to drop rows where `var1 == 1`.

It looks like this is occurring because any [comparison with `NA` returns `NA`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28857653/removing-na-observations-with-dplyrfilter), which `filter` then drops.  So, for example, `filter(dat, !(var1 %in% 1))` produces the correct results.  But is there a way to tell `filter` not to drop the `NA` values?

Comment: @akrun For some reason I didn't get this notification :P. Well I thought that the OP already knows about this, as he mentioned `filter(dat, !(var1 %in% 1))` which is similar, but I think this would be the only way to do it with `dplyr::filter`.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to explicitly tell `filter` not to drop `NA` values but in general, logical NA queries can be intuitively handled using the base `%in%` operator and it's negation, defined as `%ni% <- Negate('%in%')`. Thus, you could use `filter(dat, var1 %ni% 1)` which will work. 

See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11303276/4269699 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/27015823/4269699

Comment: Yes, I did know about both this approach and the approach that @LyzandeR used for an answer.  It looks like filter doesn't have an explicit option for "keep NA", so these workarounds will be fine.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Argh this happened to me and I was going crazy trying to understand why I was losing so much data. Agreed this seems like it is not ideal...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use this:

```
 filter(dat, var1 != 1 | is.na(var1))
  var1
1 <NA>
2    3
3    3
4 <NA>
5    2
6    2
7 <NA>
```

And it won't.

Also just for completion, dropping NAs is the intended behavior of `filter` as you can see from the following:

```
test_that("filter discards NA", {
  temp <- data.frame(
    i = 1:5,
    x = c(NA, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L)
  )
  res <- filter(temp, x == 1)
  expect_equal(nrow(res), 2L)
})
```

This test above was taken from the tests for `filter` from [github](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/tests/testthat/test-filter.r).

Comment: Venturing a bit into opinion-based territory, do you have an idea why this is the chosen approach? This behavior was unexpected to me (I got bitten by it today).

Comment: @Heisenberg I am assuming according to Hadley most people would like not to get any NAs when filtering. But that is a question for the developer / maintainer i.e. Hadley.

Answer (score 1):

The answers previously given are good, but when your filter statement involves a function of many fields, the work around might not be so great.  Also, who wants to use `mapply` the non-vectorized `identical`.  Here is another somewhat simpler solution using `coalesce`

```
filter(dat, coalesce( var1 != 1, TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

I often map `identical` with `mapply`...

(note: I believe because of changes in R 3.6.0, `set.seed` and `sample` end up with different test data)

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
set.seed(919)
(dat <- data.frame(var1 = factor(sample(c(1:3, NA), size = 10, replace = T))))
#>    var1
#> 1     3
#> 2     1
#> 3  <NA>
#> 4     3
#> 5     1
#> 6     3
#> 7     2
#> 8     3
#> 9     2
#> 10    1

filter(dat, var1 != 1)
#>   var1
#> 1    3
#> 2    3
#> 3    3
#> 4    2
#> 5    3
#> 6    2

filter(dat, !mapply(identical, as.numeric(var1), 1))
#>   var1
#> 1    3
#> 2 <NA>
#> 3    3
#> 4    3
#> 5    2
#> 6    3
#> 7    2
```

it works for numerics and strings as well (probably more common use case)...

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
set.seed(919)
(dat <- data.frame(var1 = sample(c(1:3, NA), size = 10, replace = T),
                   var2 = letters[sample(c(1:3, NA), size = 10, replace = T)],
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
#>    var1 var2
#> 1     3 <NA>
#> 2     1    a
#> 3    NA    a
#> 4     3    b
#> 5     1    b
#> 6     3 <NA>
#> 7     2    a
#> 8     3    c
#> 9     2 <NA>
#> 10    1    b

filter(dat, !mapply(identical, var1, 1L))
#>   var1 var2
#> 1    3 <NA>
#> 2   NA    a
#> 3    3    b
#> 4    3 <NA>
#> 5    2    a
#> 6    3    c
#> 7    2 <NA>

filter(dat, !mapply(identical, var2, 'a'))
#>   var1 var2
#> 1    3 <NA>
#> 2    3    b
#> 3    1    b
#> 4    3 <NA>
#> 5    3    c
#> 6    2 <NA>
#> 7    1    b
```