# R: how do I remove from a vector terms that are in another vector?

Tags: r, vector, comparison

In a toy problem of mine, I have a vector `a` made of integers and I want to efficiently remove from `a` terms that are also in a vector `b`. I wrote the code

```
newa=NULL
for (j in 1:length(a))
   if (min(abs(a[i]-b))>0) newa=c(newa,a[i])
```

but this is terrible...

Comment: Lots of similar related questions, [here is one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494848/standard-way-to-remove-multiple-elements-from-a-dataframe/7498829#7498829)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use `intersect`, `setdiff`, etc (see `?setdiff`):

```
a <- 1:10
b <- c(2, 3, 5, 7)

setdiff(a, b)
# [1]  1  4  6  8  9 10
```

Or even just use `%in%`:

```
a[!(a %in% b)] # (a %in% b) is TRUE in index i if a[i] is in b.
```

Answer (score 2):

It's lightening fingers like mathematical.coffee that make it so I never get to answer questions :P

I do this a lot using %in%. And I nabbed a great little bit of code from Stephen Turner that makes it even easier!

```
## Returns a logical vector TRUE for elements of X not in Y
"%nin%" <- function(x, y) !(x %in% y)
```