# undebug all functions

Tags: r, debugging

Consider we have called `debug()` for several functions to make a breakpoint on them. When we find and solve the bug, is there anyway to `undebug()` all functions already marked by `debug()` by a single command?

Here is a good benchmark to see if your proposed method really works perfectly:

```
> library(limma) # bioconductor
> debug(read.ilmn)
> read.ilmn("a.txt") # No problem if this file does not exist
Browse[2]> debug(.read.oneilmnfile) # This is the debug browser for read.ilmn()
Browse[2]> Q # To exit debug browser
> undebug.all() # Here run your proposed function to undebug everything!
> read.ilmn("a.txt")
# Now if the debug browser is not started, you are lucky to pass this test!
```

You may see the accepted answer below. Any case for which this answer does not work, or cleaner versions, are more than welcome.

Comment: never tried this, but seems like the sort of thing that  `lapply(yourListOfFunctions, undebug)` could do. Not sure if you need to reassign it or not...

Comment: Do we know anything more about the functions? Are these in your own package (so we can assume a particular environment or namespace), or just functions in the workspace/global environment?

Comment: `eapply(.GlobalEnv,function(x) if(is.function(x)) undebug(x))`?

Comment: @GavinSimpson Edited it with `is.function`

Comment: +1 -- This is a great question, and I wish there was a straightforward way to do it...

Comment: I modified my answer so that it now appears to work with your example.  It's really not very surprising that undebugging a *hidden* function (i.e. one whose name starts with `.`) would fail, although there is a workaround in this case (add `all.names=TRUE` to the `ls()` call)

Comment: @BenBolker, Have you checked with the benchmark I provided in my question? I tested, and it is still not killing the debug

Comment: it works for me.  did you update your code?

Comment: @BenBolker Yes I did. Let me restart my R

Comment: note that my function is called `undebug_all`, you renamed it to `undebug.all`.  Are you **sure** you modified the function definition for the update?  I have posted the code at http://www.math.mcmaster.ca/bolker/R/misc/undebug_all.R ...

Comment: @BenBolker Please see https://gist.github.com/3861959

Comment: apparently it matters whether one calls `read.ilmn()` or `read.ilmn("a.txt")`, although I don't see why at the moment ...

Comment: I'm still working on this.  Digging unexported functions out of namespaces is a pain in the butt.

Comment: @BenBolker It would be a great news of you if you can completely solve the problem and publish a function we can rely on! I think this is the first trial of this kind.

Comment: so -- does the current version work for you?

Comment: @BenBolker: Perfect, finally the answer is found. Well done!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This was my solution ...

**edit**: revised to deal with finding objects in namespaces. The code is already getting a little bit crufty, since I don't really understand the methods for manipulating/querying namespaces all that well, and since I was working by trial and error.  Cleaner versions would be welcome.  There are almost certainly other corner cases that will fail.

```
## return the names of the objects (from a vector of list of
## names of objects) that are functions and have debug flag set
isdebugged_safe <- function(x,ns=NULL)  {
    g <- if (is.null(ns)) get(x) else getFromNamespace(x,ns)
    is.function(g) && isdebugged(g)
}

which_debugged <- function(objnames,ns=NULL) {
    if (!length(objnames)) return(character(0))
    objnames[sapply(objnames,isdebugged_safe,ns=ns)]
}

all_debugged <- function(where=search(), show_empty=FALSE) {
    ss <- setNames(lapply(where,function(x) {
        which_debugged(ls(x,all.names=TRUE))
        }),gsub("package:","",where))
    ## find attached namespaces
    ## (is there a better way to test whether a 
    ##    namespace exists with a given name??)
    ns <- unlist(sapply(gsub("package:","",where),
                 function(x) {
                     if (inherits({n <- try(getNamespace(x),silent=TRUE)},
                         "try-error")) NULL else x
                 }))
    ss_ns <- setNames(lapply(ns,function(x) {
        objects <- ls(getNamespace(x),all.names=TRUE)
        which_debugged(objects,ns=x)
        }),ns)
    if (!show_empty) {
        ss <- ss[sapply(ss,length)>0]
        ss_ns <- ss_ns[sapply(ss_ns,length)>0]
    }
    ## drop overlaps
    for (i in names(ss))
        ss_ns[[i]] <- setdiff(ss_ns[[i]],ss[[i]])
    list(env=ss,ns=ss_ns)
}

undebug_all <- function(where=search()) {
    aa <- all_debugged(where)
    lapply(aa$env,undebug)
    ## now debug namespaces
    invisible(mapply(function(ns,fun) {
        undebug(getFromNamespace(fun,ns))
    },names(aa$ns),aa$ns))
}
```

The code is also posted at http://www.math.mcmaster.ca/bolker/R/misc/undebug_all.R

Example:

```
library(nlme)
debug(lme)
## define functions
source(url("http://www.math.mcmaster.ca/bolker/R/misc/undebug_all.R"))
undebug_all()
fm1 <- lme(distance ~ age, data = Orthodont) # from ?lme
```

In this case `lme` runs without entering the debugger.

Another, harder example:

```
library(limma)
source(url("http://www.math.mcmaster.ca/bolker/R/misc/undebug_all.R"))
debug(read.ilmn)
debug(limma:::.read.oneilmnfile)
all_debugged()
undebug_all()
read.ilmn()
read.ilmn("a.txt")
```

*Note* that `read.ilmn()` and `read.ilmn("a.txt")` appear to behave differently from a debugging standpoint (I don't understand why ...)

Comment: Thanks. I set a debug() on a function defined in a package, and run this code, but it did not undebug() that function. Could you please check and modify?

Comment: if you give me a reproducible example, I'll try to figure it out.  I've added an example that *does* work to my answer above.

Comment: library(limma); debug(read.ilmn); Then run your program and run read.ilmn(someFile)

Comment: I modified the question and added a benchmark for your method. Please test it.

Comment: @BenBolker: The above mcmaster link to undebug_all does not work for me.

Comment: oops, fixed now.  (Still haven't gotten through all the namespace issues, will update if/when I figure it out ...)

Comment: @BenBolker I have added your function in my .Rprofile. Today I got the following error while running it, with no arguments: Error in get(x, envir = ns, inherits = FALSE) : invalid first argument. Could you please resolve it?

Comment: How can I possibly resolve it without a reproducible example?  Have you used `traceback()`, `options(error=recover)`, etc., to try to debug it yourself?

Comment: @BenBolker In some situation I should run the function two times to work. Running only one time remains some functions on debug mode, while the second run voids every debug. Do you have any idea?

Comment: It's really nearly impossible to debug these things without a reproducible example: sorry.

Answer (score 16):

No, there is no completely reliable way to `undebug()` all functions. (I only say this because I've seen it discussed several times on R-devel and R-help.)

[In this discussion](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2005-May/071119.html), Brian Ripley weighed in, noting that:

> Debugging is a property of a function object (a bit in the sxpinfo) and so you would have to traverse all reachable objects (as gc does) to find them all.

[Here's a snippet](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2001-October/015808.html) in which Robert Gentleman answers (in the negative) [a question](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2001-October/015736.html) about whether "there is a convenient way to know at any time which are the function flagged with `debug()` or `trace()` in a R session":

> You probably didn't get an answer because the answer is no, there is
>   no easy way.

Comment: BTW, this is one reason to use `debugonce()` when you can get away with it.

Comment: Indeed - `debugonce()` doesn't seem to set the information that `isdebugged()` recognises.

Comment: @GavinSimpson -- Interesting. I have never thought of *how* `debugonce()` works, and would be interested to learn (if someone knows, or cares to dive into the sources).

Comment: +1 Good Answer, well researched. As the OP has described the problem your point is well made and the only reasonable response to provide. If we can relax the scope of where functions are looked for then there are options as Ben Bolker and I suggest.

Comment: @GavinSimpson -- Good point. The operative word in my answer really is "completely reliable". In the best R-help/R-devel discussion of this (which I'm not being able to put my finger on), there was a decent amount of back-and-forth, with a couple of the core members always countering proposed solutions with some one pathological/corner case or another.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think `isdebugged()` was probably added to R sometime after the discussion in which Robert Gentleman weighed in ...

Comment: @BenBolker -- Yeah, it's killing me that I can't find the more recent discussion, since the threads I linked to are 11 and 7 years old, resp.  Among the places you'd have to search to root out all functions are namespaces, and environments (perhaps nested a la **proto**) not directly on the search path. I'll ping you and Gavin in rchat if I ever find that thread (and if it's still interesting ;).

Comment: I am very hopeful that BenBolker or any other people ideas will solve this problem completely and we will have soon a reliable undebug.all() function

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Is it possible to define a new debug() function that gets track of all functions that are set for debug (i.e. adding them to a list)? Then undebug_all() function can simply use that list. I am not perfect with namespaces otherwise I would try to write such a function

Comment: @Ali Then I'd suggest first fully reading both discussions linked in my answer. From one of those discussions, [here is a first draft implementation](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2001-October/015808.html) of what you're suggesting.

Answer (score 8):

Here is one option, assuming that the functions you are debugging are in the workspace or global environment. Any particular environment can be specified so it is adaptable but this isn't going to be something that works for any function in all loaded packages in a single go.

First illustrate via a couple of functions in the global environment:

```
> bar <- function() {}
> foo <- function() {}
```

Use `lsf.str()` to return the functions in the workspace (for use later we `unclass()` this and convert it to a list):

```
> funlist <- as.list(unclass(lsf.str()))
> funlist
[[1]]
[1] "bar"

[[2]]
[1] "foo"
```

Next, produce an indicator for these functions as to whether they are debugged:

```
> debugged <- sapply(funlist, isdebugged)
> debugged
[1] FALSE FALSE
```

OK, so `debug()` one of the functions and rerun:

```
> debug(bar)
> 
> debugged <- sapply(funlist, isdebugged)
> debugged
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Finally `sapply()` over `funlist` functions that are debugged applying `undebug()` to them:

```
> sapply(funlist[debugged], undebug)
[[1]]
NULL
```

This of course could be encapsulated into a function

```
undebugFuns <- function() {
    funs <- unclass(lsf.str())
    dbg <- sapply(funs, isdebugged)
    if(isTRUE(any(dbg))) {
        writeLines(paste("Un-debugging:", funs[dbg]))
        sapply(funs[dbg], undebug)
    } else {
        writeLines(paste("Nothing to debug"))
    }
    invisible()
}

> debug(bar)
> undebugFuns()
Un-debugging: bar
```

---

One type of debugging not picked up by `isdebugged()` is that enacted via `debugonce()`:

```
> debug(bar)
> isdebugged(bar)
[1] TRUE
> undebugFuns()
Un-debugging: bar
> debugonce(bar)
> isdebugged(bar)
[1] FALSE
```

Which just goes to make Josh's point in his Answer again.

Comment: Thanks. I put a debug() on a function I was debugging defined in a package, and then run your undebugFuns(), but it printed "Nothing to debug". Could you please modify it to work for package functions as well?

Comment: See my comment below.  It might have trouble working if you debug a hidden function ...

Comment: Nope, but you can. Read `?lsf.str` and work out how you pass the appropriate object to the `envir` argument of the function. I **did** say this would only work currently for the global environment, but tweaked the function to allow *you* to specify the environment looked in.

Comment: library(limma); debug(read.ilmn); Then run your program and run read.ilmn(someFile)

Comment: Sorry for not answering earlier, I was doing some job. I have modified the question and added a benchmark. If you are interested, you are more than welcome to challenge it!

Comment: @AliSharifi Thanks for the update to the Question as that gives a concrete illustration of what you want to do. As you can see, whilst it might not have been important at the time, the extra information is crucial to understanding the problem and testing solutions to your interesting question. And welcome to SO by the way; I hadn't got round to saying that yet.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Thanks for your kindest message. I am very hopeful that the first reliable undebug.all() function will be published soon here