# How to make 'head' be applied automatically to output?

Tags: r

I have a bunch of large dataframes, so every time I want to display them, I have to use `head`:

```
head( blahblah(somedata) )
```

Typing head all the time gets old after the first few hundred times, so I'd like an easy way to do this if possible.  One of the cool things about R compared to java that things like this are often really easy, if you know the secret incantation.

I searched in options, and found `max.print`, which almost works, except there is now a time delay.

```
head( blahblah(somedata) )
```

.... is instantaneous (to within the limits of my perception)

```
options(max.print=100)
blahblah(somedata)
```

.... takes about 3 seconds, so longer than typing `head`

Is there some way of making `head` be applied automatically when printing large data structures?

An piece of code which reproduces this behavior:

```
long_dataset = data.frame(a = runif(10e5), 
                          b = runif(10e5), 
                          c = runif(10e5))
system.time(head(long_dataset))
options(max.print = 6)
system.time(print(long_dataset))
```

Comment: Not sure what is best practice, but I reckon the `max.print` option sounds like a good bet. As an alternative, could you just edit the `print.data.frame` function to make it just print out the first 10 rows?

Comment: Use data.tables instead of data.frames

Comment: @mnel, interesting.  That sounds like a good method.  And it seems to work nicely.  It seems like data.tables solve lots of problems in fact?

Comment: @Paul, your addition of an example is very useful.  Thanks!

Comment: `data.table` will do this automatically so I agree with mnel on that one. But those are sometimes overkill for mundane R tasks. No need to bring out the ditch witch when a beach showel will do the same job just fine.

Comment: In my `.rprofile` I keep `h <- utils::head`. So I save typing by just doing `h(df)`. Does that help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd go along with @thelatemail's suggestion, i.e. redefine `print.data.frame`:

```
print.data.frame <- function(df) {
   if (nrow(df) > 10) {
      base::print.data.frame(head(df, 5))
      cat("----\n")
      base::print.data.frame(tail(df, 5))
   } else {
      base::print.data.frame(df)
   }
}

data.frame(x=1:100, y=1:100)
#   x y
# 1 1 1
# 2 2 2
# 3 3 3
# 4 4 4
# 5 5 5
# ----
#       x   y
# 96   96  96
# 97   97  97
# 98   98  98
# 99   99  99
# 100 100 100
```

A more elaborate version could line everything up together and avoid the repeated header, but you get the idea.

You could put such function in your `.Rprofile` or `Rprofile.site` files (see `?Startup`) so it will be there every time you start an R session.

Comment: This is a great solution!  Especially when combined with .Rprofile.  I know I should use data.table sooner or later, but for now all my code is still using data.frames!

Answer (score 7):

Putting my comment into an answer, using the `data.table` package (and `data.table` not `data.frame` objects) will automatically print only the first 5 and last 5 rows (once the data.table is larger than 100 rows)

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(long_data)
DT

      1: 0.19613138 0.88714284 0.25715067
      2: 0.25405787 0.76544909 0.75632468
      3: 0.24841384 0.22095875 0.52588596
      4: 0.72766161 0.79696771 0.88802759
      5: 0.02448372 0.77885568 0.38199993
     ---                                 
 999996: 0.28230967 0.09410921 0.84420162
 999997: 0.73598931 0.86043537 0.30147089
 999998: 0.86314546 0.90334347 0.08545391
 999999: 0.85507851 0.46621131 0.23892566
1000000: 0.33172155 0.43060483 0.44173400
```

The data.table [FAQ 2.11](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.pdf) deals with this explicitly.

---

### EDIT to deal with existing `data.frame` objects you don't want to convert.

If you were hesitant at converting existing `data.frame` objects to `data.table` objects, you could simply define `print.data.frame` as `data.table:::print.data.table`

```
print.data.frame <- data.table:::print.data.table

long_dataset

      1: 0.19613138 0.88714284 0.25715067
      2: 0.25405787 0.76544909 0.75632468
      3: 0.24841384 0.22095875 0.52588596
      4: 0.72766161 0.79696771 0.88802759
      5: 0.02448372 0.77885568 0.38199993
     ---                                 
 999996: 0.28230967 0.09410921 0.84420162
 999997: 0.73598931 0.86043537 0.30147089
 999998: 0.86314546 0.90334347 0.08545391
 999999: 0.85507851 0.46621131 0.23892566
1000000: 0.33172155 0.43060483 0.44173400
```

Comment: Sounds good.  I haven't quite plucked up courage to put my toe into the water with using data.table, but it seems they solve a lot of problems.  How widely used is data.table compared to data.frame?  (I guess I'm asking so I get a feel for how likely it is to be bug-free, feature-complete, and work effectively with different libraries)

Comment: @HughPerkins [The developer (Matthew Dowle)](http://stackoverflow.com/users/403310/matthew-dowle) is very active in maintaining the package and squashing bugs. The `data.table` package I believe is in general use. It even has [its own tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data.table).