# Empty plot in R

Tags: linux, r

I did a fresh install of ARCH linux and so of R version 2.15.1. But after plotting anything with the plot command, the plot window is always empty (nothing shown). Could there be an issue with drivers or something else. I have tried graphics.off() function but to no avail.

Question edited:

The plot however is visible after resizing the plot window.

```
x<-c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
y<-c(0.1, 0.3, 0.7, 1.11, 1.3) 
plot(x, y) 

> sessionInfo() 
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22) 
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit) 
locale: 
[1] C 

attached base packages: 
[1] stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base
```

Question edited:

Setting X11.options(type="nbcairo") works fine.

Comment: what code did you use that didn't create a plot but should have?

Comment: @plannapus I have two vectors x and y containing some values. The plot was working fine with the old installation. The code is

    plot(x, y)

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a complete reproducible example and the output of `sessionInfo()`

Comment: @Shahzad Same issue here -- have any luck fixing it?

Comment: @Keith Not yet. I have to resize the window every time to make it work.

Comment: @Keith Setting X11.options(type="Xlib") works fine. cairo is not working. nbcairo type is much better.

Comment: @Shahzad Cool that works. I tried defaulting to nbcairo in RProfile using the approach from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189759/expert-r-users-whats-in-your-rprofile and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes you need to execute an initial `plot.new()` or `dev.new()` to initialize the graphics device. That is supposed to be happening with plot.default() which is the function that would have been called when you gave `plot` two vectors.

There are options that can affect the graphics device call. Use `names(options())` to see the vector of names of the options list. My system is set up so options()$device sets up the quartz device defaults properly. This is an option that is defined when the grDevices package is loaded. See:

```
?options   # in the grDevices section.
```

Using ARCH-Linux means you are going down a "less traveled path". There are many more experienced users of Debian (and Debian derived variants like Ubuntu) and RH Linuxen installations. I did find two postings to r-devel from persons using ARCH Linux, so that doesn't suggest widespread knowledge. You might be better off posting to the r-devel mailing list, now that you have behavior that shows there is interactive graphics driver capability, but just a glitch in the initial 'draw' functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How exactly I can determine the current setting of the device. options("device") returns a function instead of some name.

Comment: It is supposed to be able to return a function when accessed by name. At the top of the output you should have seen "$device".  If you type options()$device you see what is returned when invoked, but without its list name. (In R lists can hold functions as components.)