# Make sure all default packages are loaded before running .Rprofile

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a couple of RStudio projects that I've set up to automate tasks like grading multiple choice tests. The functions necessary to do the tasks are just saved in a text file, and to make sure they're available to me or other users I've been using an `.Rprofile` file that just runs something like `source("MyFunctions.R")` on startup. If an `.Rprofile` file is in the base directory of an RStudio project, it's automatically run when opening the project

However, I've run into occasional errors where functions provided by the base R packages aren't loaded before the script is sourced, functions like `read.csv` or `installed.packages`, e.g.:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  could not find function "installed.packages"
```

Is there some way to wait for the default packages to load before `source()` is run, rather than adding explicit `library()` calls for all the default packages that fail to load?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This, from `?Startup` seems pretty definitive:

> Note that when the site and user profile files are sourced only
>   the 'base' package is loaded, so **objects in other packages need to
>   be referred to by e.g. 'utils::dump.frames' or after explicitly
>   loading the package concerned**.

Based on that explicit recommendation, using `library()` to load the necessary packages looks like your best bet.

Comment: Thanks, it looks I should rethink using `.Rprofile` for these kind of things. I'd been treating it as a quick and convenient way to automatically load functions and run scripts, and it doesn't seem like it really works like that.

Comment: If you haven't seen it yet, you might be interested in this SO [r]-tag classic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189759/expert-r-users-whats-in-your-rprofile

Answer (score 2):

Having been pointed towards the `?Startup` documentation by Josh's answer, it looks like adding a `.First.sys()` call at the top of `.Rprofile` may be an option, as that seems to be the function that handles loading of all the default packages. It is normally run after `.Rprofile`, which would explain the errors I was getting.