# ProjectTemplate - automating updating of global.dcf files

Tags: r, project-template

I am using the package `ProjectTemplate` to automate the loading of data and packages in RStudio. `ProjectTemplate` uses a file called global.dcf to set loading packages, loading data and other tasks.

I have numerous RStudio projects (.Rproj files), and in each RStudio project, I have a different global.dcf file. At the moment, if I amend which packages are loaded in one RStudio project, I then need to update each global.dcf file in each RStudio project.

What I would like is a single master global.dcf file. If I amend which packages are loaded in this master global.dcf file, each global.dcf file in each RStudio project would then update automatically. Is there a way to do this using R?

Comment: If this is a global change, you're really just recreating functionality that exists through your .Rprofile. There are some examples of functionality here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189759/expert-r-users-whats-in-your-rprofile . Read through this in detail: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Startup.html