# Why do I have to create the directory "~/R/%p-library/%v" by hand on each R upgrade?

Tags: r

Every time `R` is upgraded, I have to reinstall the packages I use (from sources,so they have to be recompiled for the new version). This is a correct, understandable behavior, so I invoke [`install.packages`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/install.packages.html) - and get an error because the user-writable directory `"~/R/%p-library/%v"` does not exist yet and all the other directories in [`.libPaths()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/libPaths.html) are under `/usr/` and are not user-writable. This behavior is documented in the referenced pages.

So, after getting the install error, I have to do this:

```
> dir.create(Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_USER"))
> .libPaths(Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_USER"))
> install.packages(c("igraph","entropy",...))
```

My question is: **how do people deal with this issue?**

Create the directory by hand after each upgrade? (but isn't that tedious?)

Add the [`dir.create`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/files2.html) call to [`.Rprofile`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html)? ([apparently not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189759/expert-r-users-whats-in-your-rprofile))

EDIT: I seem to recall that, when I started to use `R`, this library directory appeared without my action; but I might be wrong...

Comment: Good question, may be let's try to write a short/complete procedure for upgrading R + packages automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you could try is specifying an `R_LIBS` in a `.REnviron` file in your `$HOME$` directory, for instance I am on Windows at work so the first line in my `.REnviron` is something like `R_LIBS="C:\Some\path\library"`.

Then when you come to update from a major version change you can just use:

```
update.packages( lib.loc = .libPaths()[1] , checkBuilt = TRUE )
```

To find out your `$HOME$` directory use:

```
Sys.getenv("HOME")
```

Comment: Essentially you are making the user library path independent on the R version. Right?

Comment: @sds exactly, yes. And then the `checkBuilt` makes R consider any packages built under the old version as in need of an update.