# Suppress package loading message in R package NAMESPACE

Tags: r, namespaces

I am importing a package called "KernSmooth" and want the start up message not to show up ...

In my Description file:

```
Package: test
Title: Test
Author: Mike
Description: Test
Maintainer: Mike
Depends: R(>= 2.10.0)
Imports: KernSmooth
```

And my Namespace file:

```
import(KernSmooth)
```

But when I load the package I still get the start up message:

```
KernSmooth 2.23 loaded
Copyright M. P. Wand 1997-2009
```

Is my only option not to import it in NAMESPACE and use

```
suppressMessages(require(KernSmooth))
```

within my R function to avoid the message?

Comment: Have you looked into `suppressPackageStartupMessages` ?

Comment: I don't think you can use that in the NAMESPACE? suppressMessages does suppress the messages but I have to load the library in my function. I wanted to see if there was a way to do it through the NAMESPACE.

Comment: Perhaps use `library` instead of `require`.  I get a message with `require`, and none with `library`

Comment: Apparently the KernSmooth author wants to display this message, even when the package is loaded but not attached; you should respect the author's intention, or find another implementation that does not display a message.

Comment: I agree that the author's intention should be respected but I would much rather note use of the package in the vignette than have to see an awkward copyright every time the package is loaded. I still think there should be a way to suppress the message in the NAMESPACE so I will leave the question up.

Comment: Have you tried keeping the import and putting the suppressMessages(loadNamespace('KernSmooth')) in your package .onLoad() function ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a .Rprofile file in the main directory of your R project, in which you tell to suppress messages in response of certain commands.
Here it follows an example of .Rprofile that suppresses the startup messages for package(KernSmooth):

```
#This is the command you must put in your .Rprofile:
#obviously you can choose other packages instead of
#KernSmooth, as well as include other personal settings

suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(KernSmooth))
```

Now, every time you start your R session, you will not see the startup messages when you load package KernSmooth.

You can find more info on .Rprofile typing '?Startup' on your R console, or you can look at this discussion for .Rprofile examples: [Expert R users, what's in your .Rprofile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189759/expert-r-users-whats-in-your-rprofile#1189826)