# Problems with "gam" smoothing in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, mgcv

I am trying to use GAM smoothing in ggplot2. According to [this conversation](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ggplot2/dHchnQxPfbE/wums1biGCvAJ) and [this code](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/stat-smooth.r#L132), ggplot2 loads *[mgcv](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mgcv/index.html)* package used for general additive models only if n >= 1000. Otherwise a user has to manually load the package. As far as I understand this example code from the conversation should do the smoothing using `geom_smooth(method="gam", formula = y ~ s(x, bs = "cs"))`:

```
library(ggplot2)
dat.large <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10000), y=rnorm(10000))
ggplot(dat.large, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_smooth()
```

But I get an error:

```
geom_smooth: method="auto" and size of largest group is >=1000, so using gam with formula: y ~ s(x, bs = "cs"). Use 'method = x' to change the smoothing method.
Error in s(x, bs = "cs") : object 'x' not found
```

The same error happens if I try following:

```
ggplot(dat.large, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method="gam", formula = y ~ s(x, bs = "cs"))
```

But for example linear model would work:

```
ggplot(dat.large, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

My R and package versions should be up-to-date:

```
R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

other attached packages: mgcv_1.7-29  ggplot2_0.9.3.1
```

Comment: works fine for me. try reinstalling ggplot2 and restarting your session.

Comment: By the way, R 3.1.0 was released on 2014-04-10, try to reproduce this on a clean install maybe?

Comment: @tonytonov I noticed that too after the question. I updated to `R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10) mgcv_1.7-29 ggplot2_0.9.3.1`, but am still getting the same error message. Are there others on OS X Mavericks? Maybe this is an OS specific problem?

Comment: Supposedly yes; tried on both win and linux, issue not reproduced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that I had `summary` function assigned as `s` in my `.Rprofile`. This confused the `s()` argument in `gam` function. I guess one should avoid assigning too many shorthands. After removal of that assignment everything works as it should.

One way to avoid making packages confused by .Rprofile shorthands is to assign them to a hidden environment and attach that environment in .Rprofile. For example (the code is borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189759/expert-r-users-whats-in-your-rprofile)):

```
.env <- new.env()
.env$s <- base::summary
attach(.env)
```

Then `s` would work as `summary` until loading *mgcv*

```
dat.large <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10000), y=rnorm(10000))
s(dat.large)
       x                   y            
 Min.   :-3.823756   Min.   :-4.531882  
 1st Qu.:-0.683730   1st Qu.:-0.687335  
 Median :-0.006945   Median :-0.009993  
 Mean   :-0.010285   Mean   :-0.000491  
 3rd Qu.: 0.665435   3rd Qu.: 0.672098  
 Max.   : 3.694357   Max.   : 3.647825
```

And would change meaning after loading the package, but would not confuse the package functionality:

```
ggplot(dat.large, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_smooth() # works
s(dat.large)
$term
[1] "dat.large"

$bs.dim
[1] -1

$fixed
[1] FALSE

$dim
[1] 1

$p.order
[1] NA

$by
[1] "NA"

$label
[1] "s(dat.large)"

$xt
NULL

$id
NULL

$sp
NULL

attr(,"class")
[1] "tp.smooth.spec"
```

**EDIT** Workaround above did not seem to work in my actual code, which is much more complicated. If you want to keep that `summary` shorthand, the easiest workaround is just to place `rm(s)` before loading *mgcv*.

Comment: scoping is a bit confusing in ggplot2.

Comment: @BenRollert Yep. Assignments get easily confusing in long scripts with `.Rprofile` adding another level of complexity. Thanks for comments Ben and tonytonov. They made me think that I actually might have something going on in my `.Rprofile` as the problem could not be reproduced.

Comment: Thank you for posting the answer. You should accept it.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was caused by a corrupt version of **mgcv**. Reinstalling this package solved the issue:

```
install.packages("mgcv")
```

Versions:

- Linux Mint 18 / 18.1
- R 3.4.0

I had the same problem on two different Linux machines.