# how to permanently save options(dplyr.width = Inf) in Rstudio?

Tags: r, save, settings, rstudio, dplyr

In **Rstudio** and the **dplyr** package :

```
> save options(dplyr.width = Inf)
```

helps to visualize ALL columns in a Data Frame. 
*Great*!

But this useful saved Options setting,
vanishes when you quit the current Rstudio session.
Next time you start Rstudio, it's gone...

***Q:*** 
How to **permanently** save:
   options(dplyr.width = Inf)  in Rstudio?
(so that the saved option setting
 is available in ALL my future Rstudio sessions)?

*Thanks!*
 -  Ubuntu Linux 12.04 (32-bit) 
 -  Rstudio v: 0.99.441 + R v: 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
 -  Pale Moon 25.5.0 and FF 37.0.2

Comment: you could add it to your `.Rprofile` http://www.r-bloggers.com/fun-with-rprofile-and-customizing-r-startup/ ^ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189759/expert-r-users-whats-in-your-rprofile