# execute functions immediately when opening R

Tags: r

I was wondering how I can execute some pre-defined functions when I open R or R-studio?

I know that it sounds silly, but I installed package `praise` and sort of want to try executing `praise()` automatically every time I open R or R studio, without actually typing in `praise()`.

Answer (score 4):

For this you can use `.First()` and `.Last()` in the `.Rprofile`.

It's a typical R file, launched on startup and used primarly to export some stuff by default.

Example `.Rprofile`:

```
# .First() run at the start of every R session. 
# Use to load commonly used packages? 
.First <- function() {
    library(ggplot2)
    cat("\nSuccessfully loaded .Rprofile at", date(), "\n")
}

# .Last() run at the end of the session
.Last <- function() {
    cat("\nGoodbye at ", date(), "\n")
}
```

---

Related: [Expert R users, what's in your .Rprofile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189759/expert-r-users-whats-in-your-rprofile)