# How do I always show the line number of the error in R?

Tags: r

In R you can see the line number of an error using the following option:

```
options(show.error.locations = TRUE)
```

Is there anyway to enable this feature by default on starting the R interpreter?

Comment: Check out [Fun with .Rprofile and customizing R startup | R-bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/fun-with-rprofile-and-customizing-r-startup/) and [Expert R users, what's in your .Rprofile? (closed)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189759/expert-r-users-whats-in-your-rprofile). TL;DR: Edit your .Rprofile!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the option to your user specific .Rprofile file

```
options(show.error.locations = TRUE)
```

You can find the folder in which your user specific .Rprofile file should be using this function:

```
path.expand("~")
```

If a .Rprofile file does not already exist here, create it.

Comment: Didn't do anything for me. Using RStudio