# How do I automatically have some code run everything I open up RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server

So for example, I want to set my global options as such:

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_171")
```

for every RStudio session.

How can I write my code so that they are run at the beginning of each RStudio session?

Comment: see `?Startup` and more examples https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189759/expert-r-users-whats-in-your-rprofile (although one issue with setting options in the .Rprofile is that your script may not be reproducible if executed by another pc)

Answer (score 1):

## Options

You can add the `options` script to your `.Rprofile`.

One of the easiest ways to access this is through the `usethis` library, specifically:

```
usethis::edit_r_profile()
```

The `.Rproflie` is always run at the start of a new session unless specifically told otherwise.

However, I only give you this with a MAJOR warning - adding code into your `.Rprofile` will prevent your R code from being reproducible.  For this reason, I would strongly recommend you set the `options` call in a **snippet** in RStudio instead of using the `.Rprofile`, allowing for a keyboard shortcut to easily add to any script you run.  While perhaps less convenient, I believe it's well worth the trade-off to keep your code fully reproducible.  You can find more info on snippets with this [support article from RStudio](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/204463668-Code-Snippets).

## Envars

The `Sys.setenv` call would probably be suited well for using a `.Renviron` file.

Again, easily added with:

```
usethis::edit_r_environ()
```

Here is a nice reference to better explain the full use of `.Rprofile` and `.Renviron` files: https://cfss.uchicago.edu/notes/r-startup/

Comment: The usethis::edit_r_profile() seems to work. But the .Renviron seems to have no effect

Comment: The formatting will be a bit different for `.Renviron` files.  See [here](https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/3-3-r-startup.html#renviron) for more examples.  Also, `.Renviron` can be at the project or user level.